# Amazon Neptune: How to perform bulk update of edge/vertice properties?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to perform a bulk update of edges within my property graph using the following gremlin command:

```
g.E().hasLabel('foo').property('expiry', 1607808123)
```

The count of edges in my graph with this label is ~3 million. I expect this operation to be long running, but what I'm encountering is a `TimeLimitExceededException` exception from Neptune after approximately 3 minutes. Is there a supported way to perform long running bulk updates in Amazon Neptune?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the neptune_query_timeout value in the database cluster parameter group associated with your cluster? The default I think is 120 seconds but you can set a larger value.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/neptune/latest/userguide/parameters.html